# Access Guid verification failed

Tags: tds

Access Guid verification is failing when we try to sync/test TDS.

[image]

We tried below steps for fixing this issue:

1. Deleted obj folder.
2. Verified to make sure that Access Guid is same across all TDS projects in solutions.
3. Replaced _DEV folder with another developer for whom it was working.
4. Access Guid was same as in web.config in _DEV folder.
5. Restarted Visual Studio.
6. Visual Studio had valid TDS license.

But still issue remains same.

Any ideas or suggestions for resolving this issue will be helpful.

Comment: it might be useful to add the version of TDS, as well as the output of TDS, which contains a stacktrace. Aside: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I just had this problem... found out that there was a URL rewrite (ToLowercase) being applied to the TDS web service call...

Comment: Any solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolved it by deleting the _DEV folder in my website root which allowed TDS to reinstall the connector.